# How does the blessing that concludes Hallel start?

Tags: blessing, text, hallel

There seem to be two different opening expressions with for the blessing that concludes Hallel:

[יְהַלְלוּךָ ה' אֱלהֵינוּ על כָּל מַעֲשֶׂיךָ](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UqliAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT99&lpg=PT99&dq=%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9C%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9A%D6%B8+%D7%94%27+%D7%90%D6%B1%D7%9C%D7%94%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D6%BC+%D7%A2%D7%9C+%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9C+%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8&source=bl&ots=NZTvjsrdNM&sig=3JmeHAesIrWhlWWPvJ4cR6yNEBo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirrNPb1pbRAhXqAsAKHQSLCfcQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9C%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%94'%20%D7%90%D6%B1%D7%9C%D7%94%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8&f=false) -
O L-rd our G-d You shall be praised for all your works and

[יְהַלְלוּךָ ה' אֱלהֵינוּ כָּל מַעֲשֶׂיךָ](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/rinat-israel01.pdf) -
All thy works shall praise thee, O L-rd our G-d.

Is one version preferable and how did they originate?

Comment: My siddur has no al and says that the GRA was gores Al

Comment: We have it in a verse http://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.145.10 "All Your works shall praise You, O LORD" How do you understand the rest of the paragraph accd to the first version anyway? It's just listing people who praise God.

Comment: The Rambam has the second version http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3a03.htm#10 and R Saadya Gaon http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=207 and Avudarham, (Rokeiach http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49926&pgnum=258 seems to be a typo and he too agrees with the second version I think)

Comment: @kouty are you sure it doesn't say that he was *not* gores "al"?

Comment: @Loewian yes see here http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/ashkenaz/hol/musaf.asp

Comment: @kouty Where there does it mention the GRA?

Comment: @Loewian You are right [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42763&st=&pgnum=303&hilite=) sidur HAGRA and they said that he did not gores על it is very strange. May be I remember wrong:(

Comment: The first version would be translated "They'd praise you, O..., for all your works" rather than "O..., you shall be praised for all your works", methinks.

Comment: @msh210      "they'd" = either   "they had" or "they would"  from [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/they-d). Which do you mean?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I meant "They will" and mistyped.

Answer (score 2):

In the Sefer Abudarham,  the nusach is " יהללוך ה' אלקיך כל מעשיך"  following the verse in Tehilim 145, 10:

> יוֹד֣וּךָ יְ֭הֹוָה כׇּל־מַעֲשֶׂ֑יךָ וַ֝חֲסִידֶ֗יךָ יְבָרְכֽוּכָה׃

Bartenura mishnayot Pesachim 10, 7,  without "אלקינו" :

> יהללוך ה' כל מעשיך

I found this thanks to the hagaot in siddur Tefila Yeshara.

Rambam Chamets Umatsa 8, 10:

> יהללוך ה' אלוהינו כל מעשיך

In [siddur Hagra](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42763&st=&pgnum=303&hilite=)  also they wrote that the Gra's nusach was without  "על".

But the minhag to say "על"  exists,  I don't know what's the earliest source of this minhag.